# Flink execute statement set and datastream in a single job

Tags: apache-flink

Somehow I am not able to execute statement set and queryable stream in a single environment, if my last statement is *flinkEnv.execute*, it executes queryable stream, but not other statements in statement-set and vice-versa

```
val flinkEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(flinkEnv);

val statementSet = tableEnv.createStatementSet();
statementSet.addInsertSql("INSERT INTO OUTPUT (SELECT * FROM INPUT_TRANSFORFM)")

tableEnv.toChangelogStream(tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM OUTPUT")).keyBy(row -> row.getField(0)).asQueryableState("OUTPUT_CHANGELOG_STATE");

flinkEnv.execute("job"); // only execute queryable operator
//statementSet.execute(); // only execute insert statement, not queryable state
```

`OUTPUT` table is defined with mode `upsert-kafka` -> `OUPUT(pkey, name)`

Answer (score 0):

The API is currently limiting this functionality. Even though it would be possible by using lower layers.

The use case of statement set + outputting to DataStream API is tracked in this [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20637).

As a workaround, you could use `toChangelogStream` for `sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM INPUT_TRANSFORM")` and then register it as a table again with `fromChangelogStream` in order to reference the same pipeline in multiple `sqlQuery()s`.

Comment: But OUTPUT table is defined with mode upsert-kafka with a unique key(k1), so I need insert statement? or is there something I can do?

Comment: You can still define INSERT INTO OUTPUT SELECT X and use `StreamStatementSet.attachAsDataStream`. Where X is defined as a separate view that comes from DataStream API to power both the INSERT INTO and your toChangelogStream.

Comment: @timo walther, can you help me with this as well,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295970/flink-table-get-type-information

Comment: hi，i want to use the  statement set + outputting to DataStream API , but i can't find the attachAsDataStream api in 1.13. Is there any other way？

Comment: If attachAsDataStream is not available, the only workaround is to convert the pipeline part without sink e.g. `DataStream s = toDataStream("SELECT * FROM x")` to DataStream API. Then convert this back to Table API, this ensures that x is only read once and both DataStream API + Table API use `s`.