# Error: There is no the LegacySinkTransformation Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When using `upsert-kafka` sink with `buffer-flush` options, I'm getting below error, while the same is working fine without `buffer-flush` options.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no the LegacySinkTransformation.
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink.getTransformation(DataStreamSink.java:71)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.common.CommonExecSink.applySinkProvider(CommonExecSink.java:294)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.common.CommonExecSink.createSinkTransformation(CommonExecSink.java:145)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.stream.StreamExecSink.translateToPlanInternal(StreamExecSink.java:140)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.nodes.exec.ExecNodeBase.translateToPlan(ExecNodeBase.java:134)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.StreamPlanner.$anonfun$translateToPlan$1(StreamPlanner.scala:71)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.StreamPlanner.translateToPlan(StreamPlanner.scala:70)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translate(PlannerBase.scala:185)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.translate(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1665)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:752)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.StatementSetImpl.execute(StatementSetImpl.java:124)
at com.company.flink.FlinkJob.main(FlinkJob.java:260)
```

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/upsert-kafka/#sink-buffer-flush-max-rows

Answer (score 0):

This is a critical bug in Flink 1.14 and will likely be fixed in the next patch version. More information can be found here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24596

A workaround would be to use the latest 1.13 version or to disable the buffering temporarily.

Comment: I switch to 1.14 because of this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812504/flink-execute-statement-set-and-datastream-in-a-single-job/69814020?noredirect=1#comment123419158_69814020, thanks twalthr